# Expected an expression error, found 'WIN32'

Tags: c++, lint, pc-lint

I have following C++ code and running PC lint on code.

Question 1:

```
#if !WIN32
#define ULONG_MAX 0xffffffff
#endif
```

Above code is throwing an lint error as follows

> Error 26: Expected an expression, found 'WIN32'
>   Error 30: Expected an integer constant

How to fix above error?

Question 2:

```
const char CompanyName[] = "mycompany";
```

> Error: Note 960: Violates MISRA Required Rule 8.5, no object/function definitions in header files

How to fix above error?

Question 3:

```
unsigned long m_ClientThreadId; 
m_ClientThreadId        = 0;
```

> Note 960: Violates MISRA Required Rule 10.1, Implicit conversion changes signedness

How to fix above error?

Comment: You need to ask more in-depth questions than just "How to fix above error?" "How to fix above error?" "How to fix above error?" You should also show us what you've tried, or if you've not tried anything, read up and try something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several points need clarification.  For example, the line:

```
#if !WIN32
```

is actually well defined by the standard, and could be reasonably used
if your compiler invocations always containt `/DWIN32=1` or `-DWIN32=0`.
For that matter, the standard says that symbols which aren't defined are
replaced by `0` during macro expansion, so there is never any problem
with the line, *unless* some other convention states that the symbol
will only be defined on Windows machines, but the value it is defined to
isn't specified; in that case, you need something like:

```
#ifndef WIN32
```

In the end, it depends on the conventions you've established for
handling compiler dependencies.

On the other hand, the line which immediately follows should be avoided,
since it defines a symbol (`ULONG_MAX`) which is defined in the C and
C++ standards.  The three line sequence here should be replaced by:

```
#include <limits.h>
```

With regards to the second question, I'm not sure if the error isn't a
miss-interpretation of the MISRA rule.  In C++, `const` implies internal
linkage by default: defining the symbol like this in a header will cause
multiple instantiations of the variable (with a different address in
each translation unit), but will not cause problems with multiple
definitions.  And the alternatives also have their disadvantages.  My
preference here would be to replace the variable definition with a
macro:

```
#define CompanyName "mycompany"
```

but macros have their own problems.  Declaring the symbol `extern`, and
then defining it in one (and only one) source file is another
alternative, but this involves two statements, in two different files,
where (depending on the role the variable plays), one might be
preferable.  (Judging by the name, I don't think the two statements
would be an issue, but there are other cases where it is preferable to
keep the text visible in the header.)  Leaving it as you've written it
is also a viable alternative, unless your company has strict rules
against it.

With regards to the last point, the expression `0` has type `int`, which
is signed.  You can clearly specify the type, `0UL`, but frankly, this
shouldn't be necessary: `0` is `0`, regardless of the type, and while
there may be cases where you want to force the type, to ensure that
arithmetic takes place in a certain way, this isn't one of them.  As for
the error/warning, I suspect that this is also a mis-interpretation of
the MISRA rules; implicit conversions which change signedness can be
problematic, but not when what is being converted is a very small
non-negative constant integer.  So write `0UL` if you need to to adhere
to company rules, but do realize that this is carrying things to the
point of silliness: a case of a basically sound rule being applied in
cases where it isn't relevant.

Comment: +1 for the answer and I would love to give another +1 for *this is carrying things to the point of silliness*. Static analyzers are there to *help* detecting potential issues, but that does not mean that every line where they complain *must* be changed, just reviewed.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas And there's nothing which forbids programming a bit of common sense into the static analyzer.  Notifying about implicit conversions which can result in a value change is very good.  Notifying about implicit conversions which might affect how an expression is evaluated too.  Notifying about an implicit conversion of `0` is just noise, and reduces the utility of the tool.

Comment: The MISRA rules that were mentioned in the question are MISRA C 2004 rules, not MISRA C++ rules.  In C, const doesn't imply internal linkage so there is no consideration of this in MISRA C, the reported violation of 8.5 is valid.  Rule 10.1 absolutely prohibits assigning or initializing an unsigned variable with an unadorned 0, this has made clear in the Exemplar Suite and the MISRA discussion forum.  PC-Lint isn't misinterpreting anything here, it's just doing its job; MISRA warnings are not provided unless they are asked for and are easy enough to disable.

Comment: @RobertGamble OK.  But prohibiting initialization with an unadorned 0 seems like a very stupid rule.  (From what I've seen to date, MISRA rules are not stupid.  Excessive, maybe, but then, they're designed for use where excessively restrictive rules are justified.  But not stupid.  I wonder what the justification is.)

Comment: @James My point was simply that PC-Lint was just following the rules.  The justification for not having an exception to Rule 10.1 for 0 is consistency.

Answer (score 4):

**First:**

You need to do this instead:

```
#ifndef WIN32
#define ULONG_MAX 0xffffffff
#endif
```

**Second:**

You can't define that in a header file, otherwise the same symbol will appear in multiple compilation units.

What you need to do instead, is just declare in the header:

```
extern const char CompanyName[];
```

And then define it once in one of the modules:

```
const char CompanyName[] = "mycompany";
```

**Third:**

```
unsigned long m_ClientThreadId; 
m_ClientThreadId        = 0;
```

This is unusual, but it seems that `0` is a signed constant. And assigning it to `unsigned long` has a implicit type cast. Most compilers do not actually warn against this.

Comment: +1, but note that while the change proposed for 2) will silence the static analyzer, I would not do it. The reason is that in C++ constants have *internal linkage*, so having the constant redefined in all translation units (TUs) that include that header will not cause an error. By performing the suggested change, in all but one TU the variable will have an incomplete type (size of the array unknown) and that will limit the usage (not much, but you cannot statically obtain the size), the alternative is manually providing the size in the header, but that adds cost to maintenance: manual updates.

Comment: I suppose the other option is to leave the definition in the header, but declare it static. That'll prevent dupe symbols at compile time, but will result in multiple copies of it. Another option is to use a macro: `#define CompanyName "mycompany"`.

Comment: *extern* consts do not have internal linkage, so this is fine. The size of the array is handy for template tricks and sizeof, but if you're not relying on them then it doesn't matter and the definition should definitely (ha ha) move out of the header.

Comment: @Mysticial: and yet another option is leave it as it is and ignore the `lint` warning... which is the one I would do.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, I'd guess the you should use

```
#ifndef WIN32
```

instead of

```
#if !WIN32
```

since the WIN32 macro not always exists, and you need to check for its existence rather than its "falseness".

Answer (score 0):

For question number two, is that line inside a header file? You should in general never *define* variables in headers, especially if that header is included in more than one file as that will create two copies of the same variable and will result in a link error.

Comment: This is not precisely true in C++. Constants have internal linkage (unless previously declared to have external linkage), so it will not trigger a compilation error, and in most cases the linker will remove the duplicate strings.

Answer (score 0):

There's also `#if !defined(WIN32)`, but `#ifndef WIN32` is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

None of these reported errors are C++ errors; they're style issues.

**First:**

```
#if !WIN32
#define ULONG_MAX 0xffffffff
#endif
```

This is legal.  In a `#if` directive, any token that isn't defined is replaced by `0`.  But it's probably better style to write `#ifndef WIN32`, as others have already suggested.

But really, that whole thing is probably a bad idea.  `ULONG_MAX` is a macro defined in the C standard header `<limits.h>`, and the C++ standard header `<climits>`.  Replace the above 3 lines by:

```
#include <climits>
```

**Second:**

```
const char CompanyName[] = "mycompany";
```

Legal, but a bad idea.  If the header file is `#include`d from different translation units, you'll have multiple definitions of `CompanyName`.  (I'm not quite sure what the C++ rules say about that.)  See Mysticial's answer.

**Third:**

```
unsigned long m_ClientThreadId; 
m_ClientThreadId        = 0;
```

Here PC-lint is being overly picky.  Yes, the implicit conversion of `0` (which is of type `int`) to `unsigned long` does change the signedness, but in this case it doesn't cause any possible problem.  But you can avoid the warning by using a literal of type unsigned long:

```
unsigned long m_ClientThreadId; 
m_ClientThreadId        = 0UL;
```